# Constraint Handling Rules in SWI Prolog: The `neq` constraint doesn't work

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, constraint-handling-rules

I am learning Constraint Handling Rules (CHR) in swi-prolog.

I started with the tutorial from Tom Schrijvers' [Constraint Handling Rules A Tutorial for (Prolog) Programmers](https://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/CHR/files/tutorial_iclp2008.pdf).

In p.286, the author gave an example to implement Inequality constraint.

```
:- use_module(library(chr)).

:- chr_constraint neq/2.

neq(X,X) <=> fail.
neq(X,Y) <=> X \= Y | true.
```

But it does not work as expected in swi-prolog.

For example, in swi-prolog

```
?- neq(A,B).
true.

?- neq(A,B), A = B.
A = $VAR(B).
```

but it should be

```
?- neq(A,B).
neq(A,B).

?- neq(A,B), A = B.
false.
```

How can I get the same result as in the slide?

My swi-prolog version (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.2.4) on windows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [?=/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=?%3D%20/%202) for your second clause:

```
:- use_module(library(chr)).
:- chr_constraint neq/2.

neq(X,X) <=> fail.
neq(X,Y) <=> ?=(X,Y) | true.
```

Sample runs:

```
?- neq(a,a).
false.

?- neq(a,b).
true.

?- neq(A,B).
neq(A, B).

?- neq(A,B), A = f(C), B = f(D).
A = f(C),
B = f(D),
neq(f(C), f(D)).

?- neq(A,B), A = [1,X], B=[].
A = [1, X],
B = [].
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The `?=` and `unifiable` are very useful to implement constraints. I also have a question though, why there is no `$VAR(X)` in your result? Your results are more tidy than mine. For example, the query `?- neq(A,B).` you got `neq(A, B).` instead of `neq($VAR(A),$VAR(B)).`.

Comment: I believe the differences in how the variables are shown must be some changes on the SWI toplevel. I am using a rather old version (8.0.2)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a temporary workaround for `neq`:

```
:- use_module(library(chr)).

:- chr_constraint neq/2.

neq(X,X) <=> fail.
neq(X,Y) <=> ground(X), ground(Y) | true.
```

It can pass all the tests in the slide:

```
?- neq(a,a).
false.

?- neq(a,b).
true.

?- neq(A,B).
neq($VAR(A),$VAR(B)).

?- neq(A,B), A = B.
false.

?- neq(A,B), A = a, B = a.
false.

?- neq(A,B), A = a, B = b.
A = a,
B = b.

?- neq(A,B), A = f(C), B = f(D).
A = f($VAR(C)),
B = f($VAR(D)),
neq(f($VAR(C)),f($VAR(D))).

%% And some other tests which not in the slide.

?- neq([1,2,3], [1,2,X]).
neq([1,2,3],[1,2,$VAR(X)]).

?- neq([1,2,3], [1,2,X]), X=3.
false.

?- neq([1,2,3], [1,2,X]), X=4.
X = 4.

?- neq([1,2,3], X).
neq([1,2,3],$VAR(X)).

?- neq([1,2,3], X), X=[1,2,3].
false.

?- neq([1,2,3], X), X=[1,2,Y].
X = [1,2,$VAR(Y)],
neq([1,2,3],[1,2,$VAR(Y)]).
```

It seems that the current CHR implementation inhibits binding variables that appear at the head in guards (see [Check guard bindings yourself](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=chr-guidelines)), even if these bindings could roll back via `\+`. Note that `X \= Y` equivalents to `\+ X = Y`. Also, the unification predicate `=` in guards seems only comparing with variables' identifier instead of unifying them.

The drawback of this workaround is that, for example,

```
?- neq(A,B), A = [1,X], B=[].

A = [1,$VAR(X)],
B = [],
neq([1,$VAR(X)],[]).
```

Since `A` is not ground, the second rule doesn't fire, but we know that `A` and `B` cannot be equal, i.e. `neq([1,$VAR(X)],[])` should have been removed.

Anyway, it's just a temporary workaround. If someone has a better solution or explanation, I could delete this answer.